# Pandas join on tuple and frozenset field

Tags: python, pandas, tuples

I want to a do a join on common field Products. But this common field is represented as different schema in both dataframes as depicted below:

df1 [frozensets]

```
Products    Products1   
0   (A, C)  (B) 
1   (A, B)  (C) 
2   (C, B)  (A) 
3   (A)     (C, B)  
4   (C)     (A, B)
```

df2 [tuples]

```
Region  Products

France  ('A','B')
France  ('C')
France  ('B','D')
France  ('C','A','B')
France  ('A','B')
```

In df2, Products are represented as tuples but not in df1. Can someone help me to convert df1['Products'] to tuple so that I can do this join

```
s1 = pd.merge(df1, df2, how='left', left_on='Products',right_on='Products')
```

Comment: What are `Products` in `df1` represented as? e.g. you can try `type(df1['Products'].iloc[0])`.

Comment: are you sure that the element inside the tuples in products of the df1 are strings ? because i can see that in df2 they are characters.

Comment: When I typed df1.dtypes  and df2.dtypes it gives me object in both the frames.

Comment: @P.hunter Yes thats the problem. They are represented as shown above. Any suggestions how to fix this?

Comment: @user2906657, what about type(df1['Products'].iloc[0]) ?

Comment: @jp_data_analysis It's gives me frozen set. Thats the problem. It is not allowing any modification.

Comment: The real problem: is (A, B) considered the same as (B, A) for the purposes of your merge? frozensets are unordered, while tuples are ordered.

Answer (score 0):

so as the elements are not in string (which they should've been by logic), we can typecast them and make a new tuple of `df1` products.

you can try something like this

```
df_pros = df1['Products'] # or some another way to select all the products from df_1
df_mod = tuple(map(lambda x: (str(x[0]), str(x[1])) if len(x) == 2 else (str(x[0])), list(map(list, df_pros))))
s1 = pd.merge(df_mod, df2, how='left', left_on='Products',right_on='Products')
```

Comment: It appears that df1['Products'] is a frozen set. When I execute the second line of your solution it gives me : 'TypeError: 'frozenset' object does not support indexing'

Comment: first we need to ask is ('A', 'B') the same as ('B', 'A') for the merge. frozensets are unordered; tuples are ordered.

Comment: are we merging on frozensets or merging on tuples? it can make a difference!

Comment: Here ('A','B ') is same as ('B','A'). Actually this data set is in reference to market basket. So customer has bought A and B or B and A is same.

Comment: Also @P.hunter still your solution gives  'list index out of range'error.

Comment: moreover considering that fact that the merge operation doesn't recognizes ('A', 'B') and ('B', 'A') as same could be an issue.